# OSX: "Due date" in Smart Folders

Tags: macos, mac, macos-mojave

When creating a Smart Folder in OSX, there appears to be a "Due Date" option. This got me all excited to add due dates to files, folders, etc. but I don't see how to accomplish this and Google doesn't help. Does anyone know if Due Dates in smart folders is actually a thing, or do I have it mischaracterized?

Answer (score 0):

It's not something I've ever really played with - but it's very likely only useful for Reminders.

Apple KB - [Reminders User Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/reminders/welcome/mac)

Comment: Sadly you are probably right.